# react-hook-form not triggering onSubmit when using Controller

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, yup

I have the following form:

```
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          name="voucherPrice"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={false}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref } }) => (
            <Input {...field} onChange={(ev) => handlePriceInputChange(ev)} value={price} type="number" innerRef={ref} />
          )}
        />

        <p>{errors.voucherPrice?.message}</p>

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ mt: 1, mr: 1 }}
          type="submit"
        >
          {"Continue"}
        </Button>
      </form>
```

and with this configuration:

```
function PriceSelection(props) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("does not work?", data);
  };

  const classes = useStylesPriceSelection();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");


  const handlePriceInputChange = (ev) => {
    console.log("change", price);
    setPrice(parseInt(ev.target.value));
  };
```

The function `onSubmit` does not trigger when I press the submit button. Also I would like the input field to be filled by default by the state `price` and its value to be sent with the parameter `data` on the function `onSubmit` when I push the submit button.

Comment: You don't want to be calling your `handleSubmit` function inside `onSubmit` instead of `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}` you want to do `onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)}`.

What is it that you're trying to do exactly? Because you're trying to console.log `data` but you're not passing in any data into the function.

Comment: with that console log I am just trying to see if the data is passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing `useState` with `react-hook-form` and are not updating `react-hook-form`'s internal form state. You don't need to declare a `useState` for your field.

In your example you are destructering `onChange` from the `field` object of `<Controller />` but you are never using it for your `<Input />` component. Therefore `react-hook-form` can't update it's form state. As you set your field to be required the `onSubmit` callback won't get triggered because `react-hook-form` will never receive an update or value for it.

The correct way would be:

```
<Controller
  name="voucherPrice"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { ref, onChange, value, ...field } }) => (
    <Input {...field} onChange={onChange} value={value} type="number" innerRef={ref} />
  )}
/>
```

Or even shorter:

```
<Controller
  name="voucherPrice"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
    <Input {...field} type="number" innerRef={ref} />
  )}
/>
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to have access to the value outside of the `<Controller />`, you should use `react-hook-form`'s `watch` method. This will allow you to subscribe to the latest value of the `voucherPrice` field and use it inside your component -> [Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch)

If you want to set or update the value programmatically you can use the `setValue` method from `react-hook-form` -> [Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue)

```
const { control, handleSubmit, watch, setValue } = useForm();

const voucherPrice = watch("voucherPrice");

const onButtonClick = () => {
  setValue("voucherPrice", <newValue>);
}
```

If you really need to have a separate `useState` for your value and want to update it additionally to your `react-hook-form` field update, you could do the following:

```
<Controller
  name="voucherPrice"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { ref, onChange, value, ...field } }) => (
    <Input
      {...field}
      onChange={(v) => {
        onChange(v);
        handlePriceInputChange(v);
      }}
      value={value}
      type="number"
      innerRef={ref}
    />
  )}
/>
```

But i would suggest to use the `react-hook-form` only solution, as it has all the functionality you need to manage your form state.

Comment: The thing is, I need the onChange function and the state so it can be shown in "value" all the time (value also gets set by a function triggered by a button, that suggests a price to the user)

Comment: so with that example, I miss on that functionality

Comment: I updated my answer to match your requirements.

Comment: thank you, that was it